# Find/list files ignoring uppercase/lowercase

Tags: bash, awk, grep, ls

How to list/find files that may or may not have uppercase letters.
Lets say i have files in a folder: README.txt, Readme.txt, readme.txt, Readme.TXT, LICENCE.txt, licence.txt etc
How do i list only files that have "readme" in file name and ignore all others.
I can't use [A-Z] or [a-z]. Is there a better way to list all those readme.txt files?
I know that [:alpha:] will ignore upper/lowercase - how to use it with ls of find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
ls | grep -i '^readme.txt$'
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "readme.txt"
```

First `ls` command would search for readme.txt ignoring the case using -i option in grep.

Find command would find readme.txt by ignoring case in your current directory.